# I want imporve accuracy in this search

Tags: php, search, directory

I created a page named index.html and in action i mentioned se.php to redirect the user to the input file name ! This is how i do it:

```php
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $cur) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($filename);   
    if($file_info['extension'] === 'php') { 
        echo "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=0 src='$filename'></iframe>";
    }
}
?>
```

this code lets the user see all files in ( work ) directory regardless of user input! I want to develop this search so that if the user entered 1, the file named 1.htm opens directly or if the user entered 2 the file named 2.htm opens directly. I don't want open all files in the directory, I want the user see the file with respect to the number that entered in the search.

thanks for your helps ..
regards;

Comment: So, in foreach loop check if the file name contains the number your user searched for!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you're always expecting something like `1.htm` or `2.htm` to show up in the search, then you can just do a `strpos` on the filename to see if your search is within the filename.

```
if(false !== strpos($_POST['term'], $file_info['filename'])){
    //this is correct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this should work

```html
<html>
<title>Search for your Mark</title>
<form class="form-search" method="post" id="s" action="se.php">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" name="s" placeholder="Search" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

```
<?php

$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $cur) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($filename);   
    if($file_info['extension'] === 'php' && strpos($_POST['s'], $file_info['filename']) !== false) { 
        echo "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=0 src='$filename'></iframe>";
    }
}

?>
```

your method should be post `method="post"`, in your `se.php` file you get `$_POST` data, and it's empty cause you use get method in html!